# Delete /dev/loopX entry after detaching loop device

Tags: udev, loop-device

I created a loop device using `losetup /dev/loop90 /tmp/disk1`, where `/tmp/disk1` is a 512M file I have created.

Then the loop device was detached using `losetup -d /dev/loop90`.

It was removed from the output of `losetup -a`, but the entry in `/dev` and `/sys/devices/virtual/block` is still present. Because this entry is present, whenever a udev scan is performed, all the removed devices are also listed.

How can these loop devices be completely deleted and all the entries removed without a reboot?

Comment: Try to use the answer(s) here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881134/cannot-delete-device-dev-loop0 - to make sure the loop device isn't still in use, then try `losetup -d` again.

Comment: I would have expected `losetup /dev/loop90 /tmp/disk1` to fail if `/dev/loop90` didn't exist in the first place (or if its minor number referred to a loop number greater than the `max_loop` parameter (/sys/module/loop/parameters/max_loop))

Comment: @schaiba I just created and detached. No mount operations were performed in between. and `fuser` returned no outout.